# Where should I search uncompressed .css?

Tags: theming

I try to update styles on a Drupal site. But when I go to `sites/default/files/css/` I find only set of gzipped .css files. Where should I search uncompressed files to edit them? Developer Tools shows path to gzipped files, naturally.

Comment: CSS files should be in your theme folder. sites/all/themes/your_theme/.

Comment: @sareed thanks! If I make some changes in css file from this folder, do they apply automatically to zipped version? And why gzipped and initial css can be different? I've just encountered with such moment: the style rule I need exists in compressed version, but is absent in initial file - why?

Comment: Automatically, maybe. Depends on your set up. The theme CSS files can be different than the aggregated files, especially if you have not cleared the cache since updating it. If you are running SASS or something like it you may have to modify those files instead of your .css files in your theme folder and then compile them.

Comment: When I cleared site cache everything became to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> when I go to sites/default/files/css/ I find only set of gzipped .css files

You need to change your configuration.

Go to Configuration > Performance

and unchecked the aggregate and compress CSS files box, Save Configuration.

[image]

You then need to go to `/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEMENAME/css` folder and hopefully you should see `.css` files now. **(Assuming you are using Drupal 7 and NOT using Drupal 8)**

```
(might need to re-start FileZilla to seem them, assuming you are using FileZilla that is.)
```

Comment: First part OK but she then should look into the theme folders shouldn't she?

Comment: @lymannx oh thanx, I overlooked the folder path she provided. (fixed my answ)

Comment: :) Plus one Drupal cache flush maybe in the end.